# html put footer container behind main content container

Tags: html, layout

I'm trying to put the footer bar behind the main content.

the html is like this:

```
<header>
</header>
<main>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Tried using `z-index:2` for the `<main>`, and `z-index:1` for the `<footer>`. But i can't seem to get it to work.

The CSS for main and footer looks like this at the moment:

```
main { 
    z-index:2; 
    margin-top:-32px;  //  is put on top of the header automatically
    background-color:#fff; 
    border:1px solid #222;
}

footer {
    z-index:1;
    border-top:1px solid #222;
    background-color:#3b3630;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    height:64px;
    margin-top:-32px;
}
```

Here's the result so far:

[image]
[image]

How can I make sure the footer is pushed behind the main content?

Comment: you could always give your main a margin-bottom of 64px and set overflow to visible?

Comment: z-index will work just when you set position in css explicitly ...

Comment: There's really not much more to add.  But @nevermind got it. I sat z-index to -1 for the footer, and position to relative...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change element's `position` property to another value than default `static` in order to make `z-index` have an effect.

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).

Reference: [Css-Tricks - z-index](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)